# Preventing a checkbox Checked event

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a `checkbox` on which I want to ask the user if he is sure or I will cancel the operation.

I tried the `Click` event but it turns out it is only being called after the `CheckedChanged` event.

I thought I could at least do it "ugly" by asking the user inside the `CheckedChanged` event but then if he wishes to cancel I need to change the `Checked` value what raises the event all over again.

Another thing I would prefer to avoid with this solution is that even before the user replies, the tick mark appears in the `checkbox`.

I'm looking for an event that happens before the `CheckedChanged` or a way to prevent the `CheckedChanged` event.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set `AutoCheck` to `false`. and handle the `Checked` state in the `Click` event.

Answer (score 2):

Find the Sample Code. It just removes the event attached to the checkbox and adds it back

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (checkBox1.Checked)
  {
    checkBox1.CheckedChanged -= checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
    checkBox1.Checked = false;
    checkBox1.CheckedChanged += checkBox1_CheckedChanged;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding up to `Sievajet's` answer.

The `AutoCheck` property is set to `false` to prevent automatic update of checkbox's appearance when it is clicked.

See the official documentation of `AutoCheck` below

> Gets or set a value indicating whether the
>   `System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox.Checked`
>              or `System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox.CheckState` values and the `System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox's`
>              appearance are automatically changed when the `System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox` is
>             clicked.

Try the ClickEvent Handler Below

```
private void checkBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (checkBox.Checked == false)
   {
     DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Confirmation Message", "Confirm", 
                           MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

     if (result == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         checkBox.Checked = true;
     }

   }
   else
   {
     checkBox.Checked = false;
   }
}
```